# About check Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) load

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-ords

In my company, we launched oracle ORDS, and we are serving 3 REST modules. But, I can't understand how to match the activity of the base with the activity of each module.

That is, I have the ords_handlers table, where in source, I have the sql that will be executed when that handler is executed, and I can associate that sql with a module, but when I see the sqls in v$sql, I am not finding how to do it the relationship.

I'm currently running ords 19.4.0, but, I'm not finding any information even going to newer versions. That is, I need to correlate the activity of the applications that use ords, with sqls that are executed in the database, in some way, to determine the load that each module produces.

Answer (score 1):

The ORDS module templates will appear as the MODULE in v and gv$session views.

My REST API with a template of 'long_running/', as defined in my 101 module:

[image]

Then when I call the API, if I go into v$session, I can see it appear as it's running.

[image]

```
/101/long_running/
```

That is the module + template of the API.

And once you have the session ID, SERIAL#...you can pull up the associated SQL of the session.

*Disclaimer: I am the product manager for Oracle REST Data Services.*

Comment: Hi, smith. Thanks for your fast answer, but, I can't see the modules values in the v$session: only this:   select module, count(*) from v$session group by module;
KTSJ                                                                      2
Oracle REST Data Services                                                11
SQL*Plus                                                                  1
w3wp.exe                                                                 11

Comment: they will only be there for the duration of the call, which hopefully is only a fraction of a second

Comment: Ok, but, then, where I can check the load by module?

Comment: all of the work of the module is being done by the SQL (or PL/SQL) so you will check AWR/ASH for that SQLID